# Convert "2011-11-04T18:30:49Z" to "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:SS a" format

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert date from this format: "2011-11-04T18:30:49Z"

To this format: "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:SS a"

With the addition of the users system currentGMTOffset offset extracted by:

```
NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];  
NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMT];
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet is going to help you to convert your formated string to a NSDate.

```
    // Current date.
    NSString *currentDate = @"2011-11-04T18:30:49Z";

    // NSDateFormatter stuff.
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];

    // Convert to NSDate.
    NSDate *neededDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDate];
```

Then you just need to convert to your requested format.

**Im using ARC so no memory management is required.**

Comment: Ok, but that creates a date with timezone 0, which is OK since the original date is at 0 offset.
But I need the date to be in user regional offset such as +5 or maybe -1 depending on the user.
You have given me half of my required answer :) thanks man.

Comment: Thanks, I basically needed to find out the time past since a time received from a server, I just got current system time and simply used NSTimeInterval interval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:neededDate]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NSDateFormatter.  You'll need to setup a date format and timezone on the date formatter object, and then you can convert strings to dates and dates to strings.

Comment: I have been trying to do this for the past two hours :(

Comment: Ok. So, what's giving you trouble?  The format strings?  Check out this reference for which codes to use ( http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns ).  You'll want to set up a date formatter with the original format which you use to convert to an NSDate, and then a 2nd formatter with the other format which converts the NSDate to the string you want.

Comment: This is what I understood:
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *createdAtDate = [df dateFromString:createdAtString];

Where createdAtString is: "2011-11-04T18:30:49Z"
But that gives createdDate as null

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString *)userVisibleDateTimeStringForRFC3339DateTimeString:(NSString *)rfc3339DateTimeString {
/*
 Returns a user-visible date time string that corresponds to the specified
 RFC 3339 date time string. Note that this does not handle all possible
 RFC 3339 date time strings, just one of the most common styles.
 */

NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

// Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
NSDate *date = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];

NSString *userVisibleDateTimeString;
if (date != nil) {
    // Convert the date object to a user-visible date string.
    NSDateFormatter *userVisibleDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    assert(userVisibleDateFormatter != nil);

    [userVisibleDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [userVisibleDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    userVisibleDateTimeString = [userVisibleDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
return userVisibleDateTimeString;
```

}

This might help.